# Why am I getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when calling getDrawable?

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable

I am trying to change the icon on a button inside a ListView at runtime, but when my code has calls to getDrawable, e.g.

```kotlin
getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause)
```

I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError from inside the activity's onCreate method. When I remove calls to getDrawable, the app runs fine.

```
01-29 18:31:43.526 30890-30890/com.p403n1x87.motee E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.p403n1x87.motee, PID: 30890
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/p403n1x87/motee/device/DeviceActivity$onCreate$adapter$1$1;
        at com.p403n1x87.motee.device.DeviceActivity.onCreate(DeviceActivity.kt:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.p403n1x87.motee.device.DeviceActivity$onCreate$adapter$1$1" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.p403n1x87.motee-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.p403n1x87.motee-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.p403n1x87.motee.device.DeviceActivity.onCreate(DeviceActivity.kt:40) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.p403n1x87.motee.device.DeviceActivity$onCreate$adapter$1$1
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 14 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace it will help a lot.

Comment: you can delete "android" inside ID tag, so it should be just "R.drawable.ic_media_pause)

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the same error when trying to get the intent from the activity inside an anonymous class instance, I realised that I should have explicitly requested the method from `it`, i.e. `it.getDrawable`. Given that the build process completes successfully, this looks like a Kotlin bug to me.